# Migrate Java app from SAP HCP trial to full SAP HCP account

Tags: javascript, java, hana, sap-business-technology-platform

I have developed a Java IoT App with Raspberry Pi which runs on SAP HANA HCP trial account.

Now I want to use it in SAP HANA account with more functionality under the SAP HANA Development Workbench.

Can I import it somehow? Or do I have to re-wright the code by myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The SAP HANA Development Workbench is the XS application platform environment and is JavaScript/HTML based so you would need to refactor the code from Java to that.

The newer version of SAP HANA with the WebIDE for HANA on the XS Advanced application platform does have Java and you could migrate that direction but would still need to refactor your code. This is part of the Cloud Foundry version of SAP Cloud Platform.